# mostrar datos de un objeto en una vista vuejs desde laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, views

Hola estoy tratando de mostrar unos datos en un componente vuejs para luego imprimirlo, retorno los datos desde el controlador despues de realizar un update bueno tengo mi vista del componente:

```js
<template>
<div class="container "   >
         <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12" >
                        <div class="invoice p-3 mb-3">
                          <!-- title row -->
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                              <h4>
                                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Comercial Alameda S.A.
                                <small class="float-right">Fecha: 2/10/2018</small>
                              </h4>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.col -->
                          </div>
                          <!-- info row -->
                          <div class="row invoice-info" >
                            <div class="col-sm-4 invoice-col">
                        
                              <b>N° Pedido:</b>{{pedido.codigo}}<br>
                              <b>Fecha:</b>{{pedido.registro}}<br>
                              <b>Valor:</b>{{pedido.valor}}<br>
                              <b>N° Documento:</b>{{pedido.tipo_documento}}<br>
                              <b>Documento:</b>{{pedido.tipo_pago}}<br>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.col -->
                          </div>

                          <div class="row no-print">
                            <div class="col-12">

                              <a href="" @click.prevent="printme" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</a>
                             
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- /.invoice -->
                      </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
<!-- /.comienzo del script -->
<script>

    export default {
         mounted() {
            
        },
         data(){
             return{
               pedido:{},
            }
        },

        methods:{
        },
        created(){    
      }
    }
</script>
```

mas que nada es el template para mostrar los datos en los campos con {{}},
ademas tengo en el return pedido como un objeto.

luego de esto tengo el controlador:

```js
public function update(Request $request, $codigo)
    {
        $this->authorize('isCajera');

        $pedido = Pedido::findOrFail($codigo);

        $pedido->estado_pedidos = 2;
        $pedido->fecha_venta = Carbon::now();
        $pedido->numero_venta = $request->get('numero_venta');
        $pedido->valor = $request->get('valor');
        $pedido->save();
    
    return json_encode (array(view('Home')->with('pedido',$pedido), 'pedido' => $pedido));
    
    }
```

aca, primero realiza un update, lo que si realiza el controlador, luego manda pedido con nombre pedido a la vista Home, pero solo lleva el registro del pedido que edite,luego realiza el return a la vista home como dije aca esta la consola, pero me tira una estructura rara.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora solo me queda mostrar los datos en el template, pero ahí es cuando me enrredo y eh tenido problemas, tengo definido lo siguiente en el js de vue:

```js
 data(){
             return{
             pedido:{},
            }
        }
```

y lo estoy mostrando asi:

```js
<strong>{{pedido.nombre_cliente}}</strong><br>
```

aparte de esto los itere para recorrerlo pero no me mostro nada

```js
v-for="pedido in ppedidos" :key = "pedido.id"
```

alguna ayuda porfa llevo dos dias tratando de sacar esto :/

Comment: En vez de v-for="pedido in ppedidos" :key = "pedido.id" no deberia ser mas bien v-for="pedido in pedidos" :key = "pedido.id"   . Sin repertir la p 2 veces.

Comment: solo me equivoque en copiar el código acá, lo tengo bien escrito, ademas solo estoy trayendo solo un objeto en el array.

Comment: Podes colocar el metodo que hace la llamada al servidor para obtener ese objecto?

Comment: si te fijas en la consola me trae el objeto, pero con dos mas dentro de el, "0" que  esta vació, no se de donde salio, y pedidos que es lo que necesito y efectivamente me lo devuelve a la vista, pero el objeto 0 no se por que esta ahí, luego en la vista lo itero para mostrarlo, pero no me lo muestra, el tema es que no los pinta en el componente de vue, pero si me los trae, pero quizás tenga el problema por el objeto vació que me trae, no lo se y no se por que me trae ese objeto o de donde sale y si se deba a eso el error que tengo.

Comment: El cero proviene del view('Home')->with('pedido',$pedido); probablemente. Estas retornando un json con una vista de primero